# Programmatically open a page in IIS/IIS Express in the default browser on click of a button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, iis-express

I want to open a html page (in AppData/Roaming folder and not in the project/solution) with IIS/IIS Express in the default browser on click of a button. I have been able to find the default browser using the following:-

```
//This method is used to get the default browser
        private static string GetDefaultBrowserPath()
        {
            string urlAssociation = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http";
            string browserPathKey = @"$BROWSER$\shell\open\command";
            RegistryKey userChoiceKey = null;
            string absBrowserPath = "";
            const string exeSuffix = ".exe";
            FileInfo browserPath;

            try
            {
                //reading default browser path from userChoiceLKey
                userChoiceKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(urlAssociation + @"\UserChoice", false);

                //If user choice was not found, try machine default
                if (userChoiceKey == null)
                {
                    //reading default browser path from Win XP registry key
                    var browserKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"HTTP\shell\open\command", false);

                    //if browser path not found, try Win Vista (and newer) registry key
                    if (browserKey == null)
                    {
                        browserKey =
                        Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
                        urlAssociation, false);
                    }
                    var path = browserKey.GetValue(null);
                    browserKey.Close();
                    return path.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    //if user defined browser choice was found
                    string progId = (userChoiceKey.GetValue("ProgId").ToString());
                    userChoiceKey.Close();

                    //looking up the path of the executable
                    string concreteBrowserKey = browserPathKey.Replace("$BROWSER$", progId);
                    var kp = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(concreteBrowserKey, false);
                    try
                    {
                        absBrowserPath = kp.GetValue(null).ToString().ToLower().Replace("\"", "");
                        if (!absBrowserPath.EndsWith(exeSuffix))
                        {
                            absBrowserPath = absBrowserPath.Substring(0, absBrowserPath.LastIndexOf(exeSuffix, StringComparison.Ordinal) + exeSuffix.Length);
                            browserPath = new FileInfo(absBrowserPath);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {      
                        throw;
                    }
                    kp.Close();
                    return absBrowserPath;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

After locating the default browser, I want to open a html page located in AppData/Roaming folder with IIS. How can this be achieved?

**Edit**: I am thinking of first publishing the pages with the IIS using ServerManager class of Microsoft.Web.Administration and then trying to open it.
is this a right approach? Once published, how would it be possible to open that page(a locally published site now) on click of some button?

Comment: "open a html page with IIS" ? Do you mean configure site at particular port?

Comment: Any port would work fine. I basically want the page to open with http:// uri (require http:// for passing postmessages to another page running with http:// protocol)

Comment: You should ask at least 2 separate questions - one how to add new site to IIS/IIS express with C# code and re-purpose this one for seeking for replacement for `Process.Start("http://localhost/myPage");`  (need reasonable explanation why that is not enough so). Please make sure to search for existing articles/questions on SO first before asking "how to configure IIS" part.